# How to manage a dynamic array of strings in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, segmentation-fault, malloc

I have a struct that represents a recipe. I don't know how to deal with ingredients and procedure because I don't know in the first place how much memory I need to store all the information.
I initialized the struct this way

```
struct _recipe
{
    char name[50];
    char** ingredients;
    char diff[12];
    int time;
    int calories;
    char** procedure;   
} recipe;
```

And I tried to allocate both of them in this way

```
recipe.ingredients = malloc(sizeof(char*) * 50);
recipe.procedure = malloc(sizeof(char*) * 50);

for(i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
    recipe.ingredients[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 30);
    recipe.procedure[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 500);
}
```

But then I have a strange output after I try to write inside of them. I let go the memory in the end of process after I printed out the strings, but I have a strange behaviour of the program most probably because I get segmentation fault but I don't get it why actually. Is that because I allocate the memory in the wrong way?
After I ended the process, it says the return value is 1.

That's the way I dereference the pointers

```
for(i = 50; i >= 0; i--){
    free(recipe.ingredients[i]);
}

for(j = 50; j >= 0; j--)
{
    free(recipe.procedure[j]);
}
free(recipe.ingredients);
free(recipe.procedure);
```

After I tried to put a counter to memorize how much memory I used and only free the unsed memory, I got this output

```
Apple pie
pø└
pø└
P└
P└
P└
PÃ└
PÃ└
PÃ└
PÃ└
└ÿc
└ÿc
└ÿc
pø└
pø└




































Easy
60 min
230 kcal
Mix milk and flour

P└
Bake them

P└
P└
P└
P└
P└
P└
P└
P└
P└
P└
P└
└ÿc
└ÿc
└ÿc
```

I know I dereferenced in a bad way using counters, but if I editer and dereferenced all the 50 elements, the program crashes. Anyway to have this result I put this in input:
-Name: Apple Pie
Ingredients: Apples
             Sugar
             Flour
             Milk
Difficulty: Easy
Time in minutes (for preparation): 60
Calories: 230
Procedure: Mix milk and flour
           Add apples
           Bake them
And the process returns 1. I know that's an horrible way to describe a recipe, I just put few strings in input to show how it ends

That's all my code, I don't know how to get rid of the error

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    struct _recipe
{
    char name[50];
    char** ingredients;
    char diff[12];
    int time;
    int calories;
    char** procedure;   
} recipe;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    char sentinel[] = "yes";
    char stop[] = "yes";
    char space = '\n';
    int counter = 0;
    int total = 0;
recipe.ingredients = malloc(sizeof(char*) * 50);
recipe.procedure = malloc(sizeof(char*) * 50);

for(i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
    recipe.ingredients[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 30);
    recipe.procedure[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 500);
}


        printf("Put the name of recipe:\n");
        fgets(recipe.name,30,stdin);
        do{
            printf("Put the ingredient:\n");
            fgets(recipe.ingredients[j],30,stdin);
            j++;
            counter++;
            printf("Do you want to continue? (yes/no)");
            gets(sentinel);
        } while(strcmp("yes",sentinel) == 0);


        printf("Put difficulty (Easy Medium Hard):\n");
        fgets(recipe.diff,11,stdin);
        printf("Put time for preparation(in minutes):\n");
        scanf("%d", &recipe.time);
        space = getchar();
        printf("Inserisci l'apporto calorico:\n");
        scanf("%d", &recipe.calories);
        space = getchar();
        i = 0;
        do{
            printf("Put the procedure:\n");
            fgets(recipe.procedure[i],1000,stdin);
            i++;
            total++;
            printf("Do you want to continue? (yes/no)\n");
            gets(stop);
        } while(strcmp("yes", stop) == 0);





        printf("%s", recipe.name);
        for(i = 0; i < counter; i++)
        {
            printf("%s", recipe.ingredients[i]);
        }
        printf("%s\n", recipe.diff);
        printf("%d min\n", recipe.time);
        printf("%d kcal\n", recipe.calories);
        for (j = 0; j < total; j++)
        {
            printf("%s", recipe.procedure[j]);
        }

            for(i = 49; i >= 0; i--){
        free(recipe.ingredients[i]);
    }

    for(j = 49; j >= 0; j--)
    {
        free(recipe.procedure[j]);
    }
    free(recipe.ingredients);
    free(recipe.procedure);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The code you posted is correct. The problem must be in other code that writes into them. You should be using something like `strcpy(recipe.ingredients[i], some_ingredient);`

Comment: @Barmar So I should create another string in which put the string so I don't get memory leaks and things like that? Sorry if I'm ignorant, I'm new on the use of dinamic memory

Comment: `some_ingredient` is the variable that holds the input that you want put into the structure.

Comment: Show the code that's filling in the recipes, that's where your problem is.

Comment: @Barmar I use a loop for the input and the function `fgets` to save the input inside the string

Comment: @Barmar `do{
   printf("Write the ingredient:\n");
   fgets(recipe.ingredients[j],30,stdin);
   j++;
   printf("Do you want to continue?(yes/no)");
   gets(sentinel);
  } while(strcmp("yes", sentinel) == 0);`

Comment: @Barmar It's the sasme with the procedure, just changing the value on fgets and the name of variables

Comment: @user3121023 Okay thank you, I'll edit on my code

Comment: `fgets(recipe.ingredients[j], 30, stdin);` should work. Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem you're having.

Comment: @Barmar I tried inputting different strings and I saw that the ingredients aren't print at all, I just see few buch of symbols while in the procedures I can see few of the procedures I put on input but I also see a lot of garbage values and there is a lot of space between the values

Comment: Don’t describe the code, show the code.  Describing says “ this is basically what my code does.”  Problem is, computers don’t do *basically* what you tell them.  They do **exactly** what you tell them.  So tell us **exactly** what you’re telling the computer to do, i.e. show your code.

Comment: debuggers are great in helping to solving these kinds of problems.

Comment: @dbush I edited the thread to show my output

Comment: In your free loop you start with `i=50` which is out of bound.
BTW thats not what dereferencing pointers means.

Comment: @Osiris even if I put 49 on the index, I get the same output I posted on my thread

Comment: @Osiris I've always had problems with dereferencing as we can see in my code, that's the part I can't deal with

Comment: @Goner dereferencing pointers and freeing allocated memory are two completly different things. But we would need more code to find your problem, please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Osiris I put my code on the thread, hope this was what you meant

Comment: @Goner You cant access the memory you already freed.
And also please fix your variable naming.

Comment: @Osiris so I should free all the memory at the end of all the process?

Comment: @Goner If you free memory you can not use it anymore, it leads to undefined behavior. So yes, free it where you dont need it anymore.

Comment: @Osiris I think I got what's the problem: using for to print both ingredients and procedures, I access to few blocks I didn't use but I need to understand what kind of loop I may use to print them without going through all the elements

Comment: @Goner You need to remember how many elements of ingredients and procedures are relevant and only output these. You output uninitialized variables which is garbage.

Comment: @Osiris I thought about a counter for each of them and put it on a for loop to print just the relevant elements, do you think it's a solution?

Comment: @Goner Yes you should do that, but i think you will still have some issues with reading your text from stdin.

Comment: @Osiris I tried to set the for loop in this way `for(i= 0; i < 3; i++)` of course this was just a way to try how the output would look and if I put three strings there's no garbage value on the screen, but I had to remove the newline from the printf because it puts two newlines instead of one

Comment: @Osiris I was wandering...I have to put all the struct in a binary file, do you think I could have some kind of issues this way?

Comment: @Goner Depends on how you write the struct to a binary file.

Comment: @Osiris is it correct to use the `fwrite(&recipe,sizeof(recipe),1,fbr)`? At least, I've always written structs this way

Comment: @Goner It seems correct to write structs this way, but in your case your struct contains pointers so you would write the adresses which the pointers hold in the binary file, which are meaningless.

Comment: @Osiris that's why I have doubts since I've never used pointers inside a struct and written it on a file

Comment: In current code `recipe.c:43:15: error: ‘recip’ undeclared`, and `recipe.c:53:19: error: ‘ricetta’ undeclared`, and `recipe.c:71:24: error: ‘SIZE’ undeclared` -- what you have posted does not compile. See [**How to debug small programs**](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Actually it does, I just forgot to edit few pieces of the code, I have to translate them so I had few problems with it, I edited now and this works

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Comment: @TobySpeight Now I have solved the problem with dynamic allocation, but I can't write both of the pointers inside a binary file and I'm having a struggle with them

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve].  I tried to reproduce your problem, but couldn't, as the program just sits waiting for input (and you didn't provide any).  Much better to reduce your code to something that demonstrates the problem without needing any input.

Comment: @TobySpeight I'm thinking about it, but I don't know how to provide an example without an input because if I try to put a value on one of the dynamic array, it gives me a segmentation fault

Answer (score -1):

Your code is correct, maybe it's the way your de-referencing?

The following works:

```
 for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 30; j++){
            recipe.ingredients[i][j] = 'a';
        }
    }
printf("Hello %c", recipe.ingredients[3][4]);
```

If you post the code of how you're de-referencing then we can help you further.

Comment: please do not guess in answers. Wait for clarifications instead. If you've got the reputation, then comment.

Comment: I know this way works, but I'm working on a school project and I rather prefer learning to use dynamic memory, but thanks for the answer

Comment: The above example is of dynamic memory, I used your code with malloc calls.